# Generate any number using Incrementation and mult by 2

Tags: algorithm, assembly

I'm looking for algorithm working in loop which will generate any natural number `n` with using only incrementation and multiplication by 2 well trivial way is known (increment number n times) but I'm looking for something a little bit faster. Honestly I don't even know how I should start this.

Comment: If your desired number is even, you can generate its half frist, then double (say, for 8 generate 4, then 4*2 makes 8). If it is odd, generate its half first (with the remaining 1/2 dropped), then double and increment (for 13 generate 6, then 6*2+1 gives 13).

Comment: Could you provide some examples? Working in a loop assumes initial value, increment and a condition and during loop operation you would be dealing with a number, so when to end?

Comment: Do you know binary numbers? :)

Comment: Yes I do, coudl You expand answer

Comment: Looks like @Drew has already done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is shift in the bits of the number from the right, starting with the MSB.

For example, if your number is 70, then the binary of it is `0b1000110`. So, you want to "shift in" the bits 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.

To shift in a zero, you simply double the number. To shift in a one, you double the number, then increment it.

```
if (bit_to_be_shifted_in != 0)
    x = (x * 2) + 1;
else
    x = x * 2;
```

So, if you're given an array of bits from MSB to LSB (i.e. from left to right), then the C code looks like this:

```
x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_bits; i++)
{
    if (bits[i] != 0)
        x = x * 2 + 1;
    else
        x = x * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to go backwards. If it's an odd number, subtract one. If it's even, divide by 2.

```
while(n > 0) {
   n & 1 ? n &= ~1 : n >>= 1;
}
```